# JPA ElementCollection within Embeddable not persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am running into an issue where nothing is being persisted into my JPA `@ElementCollection` table. [From what I can tell](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection), I think I understand the basic idea of `@ElementCollection`. My guess is that the reason something is going wrong is because I have an `ElementCollection` within an `Embeddable` Object.

A simple example:

```
@Entity
public class CalculationHistory {

    private CalculationReason calculationReason;

    @Embedded
    public CalculationReason getCalculationReason() { return calculationReason; }

    protected void setCalculationReason(CalculationReason calculationReason {
        this.calculationReason = calculationReason;
    }
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class CalculationReason {

    private List<String> descriptions;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "calculation_description", joinColumns = @JoinColumn("calculation_history_id"))
    @Column(name = "description")
    public List<String> getDescriptions() { return descriptions; }

    public void setDescriptions(List<String> descriptions) {
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }
    ...
}
```

Any clues as to what could be going wrong?

---

#### Edit: Additional Information

For the sake of brevity, I'll try to keep the additional information as short as possible.

**Creating CalculationReason**

```
public static CalculationReason create(List<String> descriptions) {
    return new CalculationReason(descriptions);
}
```

**Creating CalculationHistory**

```
public static CalculationHistory create(CalculationReason calculationReason) {
    CalculationHistory history = new CalculationHistory();
    history.setCalculationReason(calculationReason);
    ...
    return history;
}
```

**Debug Info at CalculationHistory#create**

[image: Debug Info at CalculationHistory#create]

**Hibernate DAO Repository**

```
@Override
public <S extends E> S save(S entity) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().merge(getEntityClass().getName(), entity);
}
```

**Hibernate-generated SQL**

```
Hibernate: insert into calculation_history (created_date, modified_date, modified_by, reason, system) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Looks like Hibernate is not even generating the `insert into calculation_description...` SQL that I'm expecting (ignore the extra fields)

Comment: How can anybody tell you when you dont post the persistence code, and your debugging of that persistence code?

Comment: can you please post the code where you create the CalculationHistory and fill the descriptions and the SQL that Hibernate generates.

Comment: Added more info :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After many hours of trial-and-error, I was able to fix my problem by initialising the `descriptions` field:

```
 private List<String> descriptions = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Honestly I'm not too sure why this actually makes a difference so any outside opinions are welcome.

Comment: this is so weird. this also fixed my problem

Comment: That worked for me too. Pretty strange because I'm reassigning the list later with MapStruct. It looks like for some reason hibernate expects the List to exist at entity construction.